# How do I send a message in a for loop asynchronouslY?

Tags: python, asynchronous

i have a pretty basic loop in the below code. the `send_to_space()` function is a synchronous function that awaits space's response, but i don't want to wait around for the response. i want to keep iterating through the loop and send the next item to space as fast as possible, but they have to be sent sequentially and in order so i can't batch. `send_to_space()` is a very basic api call that takes 10's of milliseconds to run due to waiting for a response and i can't change the function's contents. i also don't need the response. should i use asyncio or threading or something else? i can use python 3.9 or something newer.

```
def send_items(items_list):
    for item in items_list:
        sub_item = item['sub_item']
        send_to_space(sub_item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    send_items(my_finite_list)
```

Comment: Do you ever need to get the responses? Or just send-and-forget?

Comment: Use multi-threading to send each item in its own thread.

Comment: Unless `send_to_space` has an `async` analog, then `asyncio` won't help you. Multithreading won't be of any use if you can't tell when the message has been sent and when it's waiting for a response - you can't guarantee correct order of messages being sent. Unless the API has finer-grained endpoints for sending and receiving you're stuck with what you have.

Comment: @Barmar i don't need the response

Comment: @Woodford what if i add a small `time.sleep()` call between every `send_to_space()` call? will that help me make sure they're sent in order?

Comment: If you use multithreading and start each thread with a progressive delay it *might* work but there's no guarantee because you have no insight into when the message is done being sent - your API function is a black box. You could implement it and try and it'll probably work most of the time with a long enough delay but there's just no way to be sure.

Comment: @Woodford worth a shot. how do i do multi-threading with a progressive delay?

Comment: @Woodford what else would you need to know about the api function call?

Comment: What are the documented semantics of that call? Is it legal to invoke more than one instance at a time, or does each copy use a limited resource (like dedicated hardware) for which it requires exclusive access? This _could_ be a case where you add elements to a queue (with a buffer) in your loop, and have only a single thread processing the loop's contents; or it could be a case where it's safe to have each invocation happen in a separate thread; or it could be something else entirely -- we'd need to know what `send_to_space` _actually is_ and how it works to know which options are safe.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  the call to start each `send_to_space` call needs to happen in sequence. after that, whatever happens happens. so if i call the function at 1 second intervals and the function takes 10 seconds to run, it's completely fine for some of the calls to be running simultaneously so long as they started in sequence

Comment: Is it _mandatory_ that there be a 1-second interval between starting two separate calls, or is it acceptable if the interval between the invocations is measured in microseconds or nanoseconds? The two constraints call for very different answers.

Comment: (mind, it would be _ideal_ if `send_to_space` had a callback or other mechanism to let you know that it was done with the part of the operation that had to be ordered; without that, hacks like a small wall-clock delay between invocations might well be called for -- in which case you might have your `for` loop putting items into a queue, and a single thread popping items off that queue, starting a new thread, and then waiting for whatever delay is necessary before listening for the next item off the queue).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy no if it there were a mandatory 1 second interval, i would have included it in the description. idk what the delay would be. let's say it could be 1 second. it could be microseconds. you say those constraints call for very different answers. what are those answers?

Answer (score -1):

[Asyncio](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/) can be used for this:

```
import asyncio
async def send_items(items_list):
    for item in items_list:
        sub_item = item['sub_item']
        await asyncio.create_task(send_to_space(sub_item))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(send_items(my_finite_list))
```

Comment: Since you're `await`ing each item before proceeding to the next element of the loop, isn't the result effectively synchronous? If you wanted to decouple the two, you'd want to build a collection of futures and then use `gather()` to wait for them all _after_ the loop is complete.

Comment: yeah i said the " send_to_space() function is a synchronous function that awaits space's response, but i don't want to wait around for the response." by adding `await` aren't you effectively making it synchronous? i want to call `send_to_space()` and move on and not wait for the result